# working behind proxy servers without specifying in config

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, proxy

I am creating a web api that needs to connect to a cloud hosted web service. The api is hosted in intranet network and my org uses proxy servers to connect from intranet to internet. Thus i had to use the following lines in the config file of the web api

```
<defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
  <proxy proxyaddress="http://xxx:xx" bypassonlocal="True"  autoDetect="True" usesystemdefault="True"/>
</defaultProxy>
```

and after that it works perfectly. But I want it to work without specifying a proxy address. The reason for this is -

The proxy address changes frequently and we have to modify the file for service to work again.

If i don't give any proxy address, then it gives the error

```
The remote name could not be resolved: xxx.xx.net
```

and the `autoDetect` and `usesystemdefault` parameters also don't seem to work. 
Kindly help me in finding a solution such that the web api is able to connect to internet without specifying the `proxyaddress` attribute in config file. Thanks in advance.